# Window and Linux on multiple drives

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

Is there any problem on having Windows 10 on an SSD and Linux Mint on an HDD in the same computer and have an option to boot either one on startup? And if not how can my pc ask me what to boot when starting up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there is no problem with this. It's called dual-booting. Easily Googlable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a problem with that.  Just make sure to install Windows before Linux; the Linux bootloader should ask which OS you want to boot.

Comment: So just install ubuntu on the second HDD and when i boot  linux bootloader will ask for windows or linux?

Comment: P.S. already got windows 10 on ssd and linux mint on hdd but i keep switching the sata cable and really want to try ubuntu

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: And do i leave my boot priority on the ssd first or change it to the hdd with linux for the bootloader to work?

Comment: That, unfortunately, I don't know.  Sorry!

Comment: It's ok you helped a lot. Thanks